# Sharepoint 2010 reacts very badly to having it's IP address changed. How do I fix it?

Tags: iis-7.5, sharepoint-2010

I have Sharepoint 2010 set up on a virtual host for prototyping various projects. If I restart the host, the IP changes. Afterwards, SP complains that it can't find it's configuration database. I can't find where it might be storing an IP. To clarify, the URL remains the same - I have a dynamic dns solution in place to handle that. I can't see anything in the web.config files or the database connection strings that would indicate a hardcoded IP.

How can I fix this up in less time than re-installing every time I need to do a project?

Comment: To elaborate: this issue is not the IP, it's the server name. This is on EC2 and I only will use it intermittently to prototype SP configurations. By default the server name changes every time it is restarted. You can turn that policy off with the "EC2configservice Settings" application in the start menu. It comes with all EC2 Windows instances.

Comment: If you need to salvage a Sharepoint installation after a name change, see this question -> http://serverfault.com/questions/174870/how-to-restore-sharepoint-2010-foundation-after-pc-renaming/284101